# Using a Kubernete Ingress on GCE to Redirect/Force TLS

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-compute-engine

Am I currently forced to use an additional webserver (`nginx`) to redirect all Kubernete Ingress traffic to https when hosting on GCE?

I'm looking to deploy a Golang application into the wild. As a learning experiment, I thought I would use GCE to host & K8s to deploy/scale. I have `deployments` and `services` all working as expected returning traffic and created certs with Lets Encrypt for TLS termination.

I am at the point of implementing an `Ingress` now as `Service LoadBalancers` seem to be deprecated. At this stage I am using a static IP for the Ingress to use for `backend` requests - as follows

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "kubernetes-ingress"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: web-ssl
  backend:
    serviceName: web
    servicePort: 80`

Of course I want all http traffic to go through https/TLS. Assigning the `ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"` entry has made no difference. As a sneaky attempt, I thought I may be able to alter the `servicePort` to 443. As my service is accepting requests on both 80/443 ports, valid responses were returned, but http was not forced to https.

At this stage I am guessing I will need to "bite the bullet" and create an `nginx Ingress Controller`. This will also help to update certs using `Lego` along with creating another abstraction should I need more service points.

But before I did, I just wanted to check first if there is no other way? Any help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Ingress controller is needed to implement the Ingress manifest. Without it, installing the Ingress manifest doesn't do anything. Afaik, deploying an Ingress is the best way for HTTP redirection.

You can make the ingress redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS. Check out this [tutorial for TLS with traefik](https://medium.com/@patrickeasters/using-traefik-with-tls-on-kubernetes-cb67fb43a948#.pnp56pvx6), and this [tutorial for TLS with nginx](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/livedevopsinjapan/2017/02/28/configure-nginx-ingress-controller-for-tls-termination-on-kubernetes-on-azure-2/).

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I'm "all over" the tutorials and am progressing with the Nginx controller. Complete overkill for app requirements, but a good learning process for future =]

Comment: You're welcome :) It will be a great learning experience nonetheless.